# Synchronizing calls above the class level

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

This is a design problem where I am trying to figure out in which level(application, class, object or even finer) I should put locks to ensure atomicity.

I have an application say `Engine` which has a `class A` and a method inside which contains a map.

```
class A{
    public void methodA(){
       Map<X,Y> testMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    }
}
```

Now I have multiple threads accessing this map. What I want to ensure is **atomic {read and write} combination** on this map. Options which I have is

```
1.ConcurrentHashMap
2.Collections.synchronizedMap
3.static synchronizedMap outside the methodA
4.Application level locks using Redis or Memcache
```

What I should mention is I am considering the 4th option because the **application `Engine` can have multiple instances.**

Now I am facing race conditions when multiple threads are trying to read and write to the map.

For option1 I get bucket level lock because different threads can be directed to different instances of the `Engine` app

For option2 I get object level lock which faces the same issue as 1

For option3 I get class level lock which suffers from the same flaws of a multi instanced app

Option 4 seems the most viable option. However it will carry a performance overhead. So is there some way in Java to ensure this lock at a class level and not allow threads to modify different instances of the app.

### EDIT

With reference to Chetan's comment this local map is later used to talk to the dao of a database which is global and thats where the race condition is encountered.

Comment: `testMap` is a local variable. There is no need to worry about atomicity here.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple instances?

Comment: @KingJulien The name implies. I can give you an example say in Hadoop which has a master and corresponding slave datanode instances.

Comment: "this local map is later used to talk to the dao of a database which is global and thats where the race condition is encountered." So, map is a local variable and you dont have any race condition there... so now you have multiple instance of this map and you are trying insert/update it into a 'global' database.. is my understanding right?

Comment: I cant confidently pinpoint exactly where I am encountering the race condition but I am pretty sure that it doesnt entirely occur on account of the multiple instances of the app. Even when a single instance is running with my current implementation and different threads call on the method race condition is encountered. It can be remedied with option 3. But I need to fix the multiple instance issue.

Comment: If you are using RDBMS database to persist, it's ACID property will take care of inserts from multiple instance, I don't see a problem there

Answer (score 1):

1. ConcurrentHashMap

   even though all operations are thread-safe when you are 'get'ing, it may or may not reflect the 'put's.
2. Collections.synchronizedMap

   Collections.synchronizedMap(map) creates a blocking Map which will degrade performance, albeit ensure consistency. use this option only if each thread needs to have an up-to-date view of the map
3. static synchronizedMap outside the methodA

   same as 3
4. Application level locks using Redis or Memcache

From what I understood from your question, only this option make sense.

This is my understanding about your requirement, correct me if I am am wrong, will update answer accordingly: -You have multiple instances (as in multiple instances residing in multiple JVMs) of 'engine' application. while persisting the map (which is local to each instances) into the database you have to avoid race condition

Comment: Yes I basically want to persist this map making it global instead of local.